# How to specify a polymorphic association in a fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, fixtures

I have this fixture:

```
resource:
  name: my resource
  owner: user_1 (User)
```

Resource is defined like this:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
```

User is defined like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources, :as => :owner
```

When I run the test I get an error that the column 'owner' is not defined in the table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have the wrong migration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing a polymorphic association with fixtures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744713/unit-testing-a-polymorphic-association-with-fixtures)

Answer (score 2):

The fixture should have owner_id and owner_type. For example: owner_id as 1 and owner_type as "User"