# Unit testing a polymorphic association with fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I'm getting this error message:

```
ERROR["test_profile_display", UsersProfileTest, 2.569931] test_profile_display#UsersProfileTest (2.57s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass
        app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `show'
        test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `show'
    test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'
```

It seems `character` in the UsersController in the line `@posts = @user.character.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])` is nil. There is a polymorphic relationship between users and characters. I thought I'd used the correct syntax in fixtures to tell rails that the user Bazley has a fixture:
In characters.yml:

```
character_bazley:
  sociable: bazley (user)
```

How do I convince rails that the user fixture does indeed have a character belonging to it?

test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersProfileTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include ApplicationHelper

  def setup
    @user = users(:bazley)
  end

  test "profile display" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select 'title', full_title(@user.name)
    assert_select 'h1', text: @user.name
    assert_select 'h1>img.gravatar'
    assert_match @user.character.posts.count.to_s, response.body
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    @user.character.posts.paginate(page: 1).each do |post|
      assert_match post.content, response.body
    end
  end
end # UsersProfileTest
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  has_one  :character, as: :sociable, dependent: :destroy
  .
  .
end
```

character.rb:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sociable, polymorphic: true
  has_many   :posts, dependent: :destroy
  validates  :sociable_id, presence: true
end # Character
```

users.yml:

```
bazley:
  name: Bazley
  email: bazley@oxdorf.com
  callsign: bazley
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

characters.yml:

```
character_bazley:
  sociable: bazley (user)
```

In UsersController:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_callsign(params[:callsign])
  @posts = @user.character.posts.paginate(page: params[:page]) # the line causing the error
  @page_name = "user_page"
  redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated
end
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change `characters.yml` to be

```
character_bazley:
  sociable: bazley (User)
```

instead of

```
character_bazley:
  sociable: bazley (user)
```

Note it is `User` and not `user`. The keyword used here `User` will tell that the `sociable_type` is of `User` class.

Ref:

http://ruby-journal.com/rails/define-fixtures-with-polymorphic-association/
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html#label-Polymorphic+belongs_to

Comment: Oh dear, a capital letter... I am a chump.
Thank you.